# Unable to pull the records from Git repository

Tags: git

After my Active Directory password has been changed, am unable to pull or push records from git repository. when i google it, some people suggested to try with git fetch cmd but issue was not resolved.

```
$ git fetch

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.host.com/8800/it/xxx/ui/repository.git/'
```

Comment: which operating system you are using? is it windows of linux?

Comment: @PrateikDarji Windows 10

Comment: needs more info. What is `host.com` really? How does it integrate with your AD?

Comment: Did you try to update your credentials in your git config `git config --global credential.helper wincred`?

Comment: By trying this command `git config --system --unset credential.helper`  its work for me. @ErickGuillen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved for me by resetting my git credential by following below steps.

i. Open git bash in run as administrator.
ii. After entering the below git command my credential was unset.

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Then I given `git pull` it asked my new credential. After entering the credential, it works fine for me.

Thanks for all your support.